# Get weight scale data from serial port using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am new in node js, i want to get weight data from serial port, i have installed nodejs(v14.19.0) and npm(6.14.16), and i want to get weight data using localhost:8080/get_weight, but script is not working, anyone can help me ?

Here is my code:

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = 'localhost';
const { SerialPort, ReadlineParser } = require('serialport')
const { io } = require('socket.io')(3000);
const serialport = new SerialPort({ 
    path: '/dev/ttyS4',
    baudRate: 7500000 ,
})
const parser = new ReadlineParser()
serialport.pipe(parser)
/*serialport.on('data', console.log)  */

let express = require('express')
let app = express();

var port = 8080;

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
app.get('/get_weight', function(req, res) {
    serialport.on('open',function(){
        serialport.on('data', function(data){
            console.log('DATA:::::', data)
            const buf2 = Buffer.from(data)
            let wArray = buf2.toString('utf8');
            let wSlice = wArray.slice(3, wArray.length);
            let rawWeight = wSlice.slice(0, -3);
            let fWeight = rawWeight.trim();
            let weight = parseInt(fWeight);
            console.log(weight);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please share which errors you are getting when running the script or what exactly is not working?

Comment: @Mushroomator when i request /get_weight nothing to print in the console, i don't know script is ok or not. can you please advise ?

Answer (score 0):

your script only handles reading data from the scales. however, you should also write a command to the serial port, and only then can you wait and receive data.
please read the user manual for the device, it should have an interface to use for communicating with it.